# Loading 83mb RData Object from twitteR Package

Tags: r, twitter, rdata

I have an 83.356MB RData file that contains only one list object. The list object has 10 elements, each of which is "status" object, which is created when querying the Twitter API using the twitteR package. When I tried to load this object yesterday, I waited half an hour and it still did not load. When I left it over night, it crashed R.

So to sum up, I am unable to load this RData file into R. I didn't think 83MB was too large, and I believe it is way under any memory limitation of R, so I don't understand why it is not loading.

Comment: What was the crash message? Have you tried to recreate the file to check if your current one isn't corrupted?

Comment: The error reads "R Session Aborted  \n  R encountered a fatal error.  \n  The session was terminated."

I can't actually recreate the file exactly since it was data from a search of Twitter.com at that given time. I do however have similar files, though smaller in size, that work fine.